# How can I consume a web service on Microsoft Dynamics NAV system from an iOS application?

Tags: ios, microsoft-dynamics

I need to make an iOS application that can consume a web service on Microsoft Dynamics NAV system. The web service is given in WSDL. I tried to access the service by sending SOAP request but without success. Is there a different approach to consume a WSDL web service on a NAV system ? I am really stuck in here. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What was the issue consuming the WSDL? Using something like this will help you create the necessary classes and objects to make requests. http://easywsdl.com

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion in this situation is always to create a C# Web Service that will act as a bridge between NAV and your iOS application.

The Web Service use .NET so can easily pull the data from NAV, and because is a Web Service you can consume it by any platform (with SOAP or REST is your decision)

Comment: I tried to consume with SOAP. But I am getting "INVALID SOAP MESSAGE" response. The NAV service I am trying to consume is given in WSDL. So what may be the easiest approach to do that ? It would be great if you could share with me some approach.

Comment: the easiest is to create a proxy web service

Comment: I haven't tried it that way ..... but it would be better if I could consume the web service from iOS application directly

Comment: @GuidoPreite: Is it possible to use NodeJs for bridge? I am using NodeJS and trying to access NAV Web service but i am getting Error 401.